# Using join models in Rails. Adding an item to a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This seems like a very basic question, but I haven't found an explanation anywhere on the internet on how to do it, and I imagine many people have this problem.

I have three models: Exercise, Workout, and workout_exercise (join table)

In my join table I have extra columns associated with each exercise, such as the number of sets and repetitions to be performed. So my `workout_exercises` table looks like this:

```
    t.integer  "workout_id"
    t.integer  "exercise_id"
    t.integer  "repetitions"
    t.integer  "set"
    t.integer  "rest"
```

I can add exercises to workouts, and in my workout show view I have a list of exercises associated with each exercise.

I can't figure out how to display the sets, repetitions, and rest for each exercise in the workout show view.

Here is my code for my models:

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :photo, :video

  has_many :workout_exercises 
  has_many :workouts, :through => :workout_exercises
end

class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :workout_exercises
  has_many :exercises, :through => :workout_exercises

end

class WorkoutExercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :exercise_id, :repetitions, :rest, :set, :workout_id

  belongs_to :exercise
  belongs_to :workout
end
```

And in my workouts_controller I have

```
class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController     
     before_filter :get_workouts, :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
     before_filter :get_exercises, :only => [:show]    

     def get_exercises
        @workout_exercise = @workout.exercises
      end

    def get_workouts
        @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])
      end
```

Finally, I have this form in my workout show view:

```
<% @workout_exercise.each do |exercise| %>
  <%= exercise.name %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fields you're looking for are in the `workout_exercises` table.

In `workouts_controller` :

```
def get_exercises
    @workout_exercise = @workout.workout_exercises
end
```

In your view you can list the information as follows -- the name of the exercise still sits in `exercise` but each `workout_exercise` has a reference to the `exercise`

```
<% @workout_exercise.each do |w| %>
    Name: <%= w.exercise.name %>
    Set: <%= w.set %>
    Reps: <%= w.repetitions %>
    Rest: <%= w.rest %>
<% end %>
```

### Edit - workout_controller##  make sure `@workout_exercise` is instantiated in `show`:

```
def show
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])
    @workout_exercise = @workout.workout_exercises
end
```

github for explainz

https://github.com/twairball/workoutapp

Comment: Thanks! That almost solves the question! But I am getting a no method error on w.exercise.name: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: This blows up if your `@workout_exercise` doesnt belong to an `exercise`. Can you test in `rails console` mode and make sure your data works? try `w = WorkoutExercise.find(##ID##)` -- substitute ##ID## for a valid workout_exercise obviously, then test that exercise is not valid `w.exercise`

Comment: WorkoutExercise does belong to exercise, and testing in console returns the entire exercise with all associated rows. Putting simply w.exercise in the view returns the location in memory, so this: #<Exercise:0x007fb844597ed8>

Comment: wait... which action are you display the `workout_exercise` data in ? `@workout_exercise` is not instantiated in `get_workouts` view.

Comment: I already had a before filter for the show method. I updated the controller code in my question: before_filter :get_exercises, :only => [:show]

Comment: my point still applies, `:name` exists in `exercise`, whereas `:repetitions` , `:rest` and `:set` is in `workout_exercise`

Comment: Well adding \@workout_exercise = \@workout.workout_exercises to the show command of the workout_controller doesn't change anything, and still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I don't know how else to explain to you. I whipped up https://github.com/twairball/workoutapp for you. Also in future be prepared to offer code so others can help you.

Comment: You're right. I was getting the <Exercise:0x007fb844597ed8> when I tried using w.exercise.name because some of the values were nill. Using w.exercise.try(:name) solved the problem, and it's working great now.

Answer (score 0):

I made [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/arelenglish/6110438) to show exactly how to do this. Step by step.